# Is there a way to fade two div elements into one another in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

If I have two div elements that contain some text and I want them into one another such that as one disappears the other appears and it then repeats how do i go about doing this? I'm not sure where to where to start.

```html
<div id="body">
  <div>My great adventure</div>
  <div>Travel, adventure, leisure</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the condition for one to disappear while another appears?

Comment: Check CSS animations https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations

Comment: See [How can I fade one element into another with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850995/how-can-i-fade-one-element-into-another-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Using [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) we can achieve this pretty simply.

We will create 2 animations. One that causes the text to fade in initially, and one to cause the text to fade out initially. We will set these animations to loop forever.

You can fine tune the timings and opacity levels to your needs.

```css
.fade {
  position: absolute;
}

#start {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeStart;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

#end {
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fadeEnd;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes fadeStart {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeEnd {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="fade" id="start">My great adventure</div>
  <div class="fade" id="end">Travel, adventure, leisure</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just talking about non-animated, static elements visually fading into one another, you can use a [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) for the `background` of `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements.

Below is a pure CSS example making use of CSS variables for consistent colors and sizing. The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements fade from the background color to transparent. You can increase the multiplier in `margin` on the `#body > div` to decrease the amount of overlap.

```css
body {
  --div-bg: orange;
  --fade-height: 3rem;
  background: white;
}

#body>div {
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  background: var(--div-bg);
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: calc(var(--fade-height) * 1) 0 0;
}

#body>div::before,
#body>div::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: var(--fade-height);
}

#body>div::after {
  bottom: calc(var(--fade-height) * -1);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, var(--div-bg), transparent);
}

#body>div::before {
  top: calc(var(--fade-height) * -1);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, var(--div-bg), transparent);
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div>My great adventure</div>
  <div style="--div-bg: #33F;">Travel, adventure, leisure</div>
</div>
```